# BCrypt authentication always failing RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, where I reached Chapter 8. But the *authenticated?* method always returns false. The Cookie for :remember_token is saved properly. But as i compare the in the database digested remember_digest via `BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)` it will always return false. I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1. Here is my code:

```
controllers/sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def new
    end

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            log_in(user)
            params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
            redirect_to user
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        log_out if logged_in?
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end

models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :remember_token

    before_save { email.downcase! }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 250 }, format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    has_secure_password

    def self.digest(string)
        cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST : BCrypt::Engine.cost
        BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
    end

    def User.new_token
      SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

    def remember
      self.remember_token = User.new_token
      update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
    end

    def authenticated?(remember_token)
      return false if remember_digest.nil?
      BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
    end

    def forget
      update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
    end
end

helpers/sessions_helper.rb

module SessionsHelper
    def log_in(user)
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end

    def log_out
       forget(current_user)
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end



    def remember(user)
        user.remember
        cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
        cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    end

    def forget(user)
      user.forget
      cookies.delete(:user_id)
      cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end

    def current_user
        if (user_id = session[:user_id])
            @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
        elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
          user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
          if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
            @current_user = user
            puts "INSIDE"
          end
        end
    end

    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end
end
```

Comment: In sessions_helper => remember(user) on second line why are assigning `signed` to `cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token]` Isn't it  be just     **cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token**

Comment: Thanks so much. That was exactly the mistake :)

Comment: CamelWriter, Glad that helps you. I have updated my answer please mark that as accepted.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `helpers/sessions_helper.rb => remember(user)` on second line change:

```
cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```

to:

```
cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
```